# Are there non-trivial examples of sentences where the use of one case, instead of other, changes the meaning?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

Are there examples of German sentences where the use of one case instead of other alters the meaning, but still being the sentence grammatically correct?

*Edit*: I'm after sentences in which *only* the case changes (but otherwise the sentence should be the same).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Ich gehe hinter das Haus.

Bedeutet: Ich bin gerade vor dem Haus und gehe nun dahinter.

> Ich gehe hinter dem Haus.

Bedeutet: Ich bin gerade hinter dem Haus und gehe dort beispielsweise im Kreis.

Answer (score 8):

Da gibt es einiges. Eine Gruppe sind die Beispiele mit Wechselpräpositionen, wie von AlexE schon vorgeschlagen. Aber auch sonst lässt sich sicher einiges finden, so man nur lange genug schraubt.
Hier ein Beispiel:

> Ich vergebe ihm.
>
> Ich vergebe ihn (z.B. den Preis)
>
> Ich gestehe ihm.
>
> Ich gestehe ihn (z.B. den Seitensprung)
>
> Es passiert sie (das Lamm die Grenze)
>
> Es passiert ihr. (Die Sache der Frau)
>
> Er schmeckt ihm. (Der Kuchen dem Mann)
>
> Er schmeckt ihn (Der Mann den Geschmack nach Seife)

Alles etwas konstruiert aber was soll's.

Comment: Danke! Was bedeutet `solls`, in `was solls`? Laut `dict.cc` bedeutet es "what the hell", aber wo kommt `solls` her?  wiktionary hat keine Seite fuer dieses Wort.

Comment: Oh mein Fehler... es ist eigentlich "was soll's" und das ist kurz für "Was soll es/das"

Answer (score 3):

Hier ein Beispiel aus einem [**Artikel in der c't**](http://www.heise.de/ct/artikel/Der-Trojaner-Test-1798596.html) über Virenscanner. Die Bedeutung des Satzes ändert sich, je nachdem welchen Kasus man den Substantiven gedanklich zuweist. Dennoch bleibt der Satz grammatisch richtig. Mehr noch, äußerlich ändert sich überhaupt nichts: kein Komma, kein Buchstabe!

> virtuelle Maschinen erkennen viele Schädlinge

Wie herum ist die Aussage zu lesen? Welches Substantiv ist das Subjekt, welches das Objekt? Und kann man diese Frage auch entscheiden, ohne etwas von Computern zu verstehen?

In [**SVO-Sprachen**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wortstellung) ist der Fall eigentlich klar:

*virtuelle Maschinen* (Nominativsubjekt) --> *erkennen* (transitives Verb) --> *viele Schädlinge* (Akkusativobjekt)

Grundsätzlich müsste die Festlegung auf die Wortstellung SVO im Deutschen sogar noch stärker sein als im Englischen, da viele Substantive flektiert werden und damit ihr Kasus erkennbar markiert ist.

Jedoch werden eben nicht alle Substantive flektiert. Fehlt diese Information, kann sich Deutsch mit einem Mal in eine [**OVS-Sprache**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objekt-Verb-Subjekt) verwandeln! Etwas, das im Englischen überhaupt nicht ginge.

Hier das Zitat im Zusammenhang:

> Dass für jeden Testkandidaten dazu ein eigener PC erforderlich ist,
>   ist noch das Geringste. Das muss im Übrigen echte Hardware sein;
>   **virtuelle Maschinen erkennen viele Schädlinge** und werden dort erst gar
>   nicht aktiv.

Sinn macht jetzt die Aussage nur dann, wenn "viele Schädlinge" das Nominativsubjekt sind und "virtuelle Maschinen" das Akkusativobjekt! Im Gegensatz zur sonst üblichen Leseweise von links nach rechts muss die Aussage dieses Mal von **rechts nach links** verstanden werden.

Comment: Würd zur Maximierung der Verwirrung hinzufügen: "Er hat Angst deinetwegen." Kann man sowohl so verstehen, dass er sich vor der angesprochenen Person fürchtet, oder dass er sich um die angesprochene Person sorgt. Und ausser dem Fall hat sich nichts geändert -- kein Buchstabe. Cränk!

Answer (score 3):

It's simpler with prepositional objects as the change of meaning due to case change is smaller. Most verbs requiring direct objects change the meaning rather drastically due to case change. But this can also happen with prepositional objects:

> Er steht auf den Stuhl. = *He likes the chair. / He's fond of the chair.*
>   Er steht auf dem Stuhl. = *He's standing atop the chair.*

If you replace "der Stuhl" by a name, the case change becomes indeterminable:

> Er steht auf Susi. = *He likes Susi. / He's fond of Susi. (Susi is in accusative.)*
>   Er steht auf Susi. = *He's standing atop Susi. (Susi is in dative.)*

Answer (score 2):

Typically with prepositions that have can be followed by either the accusative or dative case, the difference is in whether or not it's modal, meaning if it describes motion or change of state.

- Ich gehe in das Haus - *I'm going into the Haus*
- Ich bin in dem Haus - *I am in the house*

The first example describes motion, so it uses the accusative.

Comment: Doch, aber da hast du das Verb geändert.

Comment: Man könnte durchaus auch sagen: *"Ich gehe in dem Haus"* ;)